# can't login mysql8.0.15 on mac os

Tags: linux, mac, passwords, mysql

- when i login as root I put in right password, it reports

[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6drPq.png)

I'm sure the password is correct (I reinstall it again and remember the password  ).

- then I search in google, somebody recommend me to log in without password, I followed het o stop mysql server and use

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

and use mysql database 
then I use

```
 SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('12345678');
```

to make a new password, however it reports

[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjeLI.png)

this problem, then I searched in google again，somebody show some ways to solve this problem on windows, others say to exchange /etc/my.cnf on some linux system, however both of them were invalid，is there any good way
to solve this problem? Please help me.